# fullcalendar: remove space after last event

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

In agenda week and day view when events are rendered there is a blank space after the last event. In older version of fullcalendar(v1.5.4) it was possible to remove this space and use the whole column(day) width in the agenda view by commenting out:

```
availWidth = Math.min(availWidth-6, availWidth*.95); // TODO: move this to CSS
```

in

```
function renderSlotSegs(segs, modifiedEventId)
```

This fix is no longer valid for v. 1.6.4. Anyone knows a fix for this new version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that commenting out:

```
columnRight -= columnWidth * .025;
```

in

```
function renderSlotSegs(segs, modifiedEventId)
```

does what I wanted to do. If anyone has a better solution of doing this without changing the plugin code it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems to only show when you manipulate the minTime and maxTime; at this it did for me.

Comment: Just found this solution that worked for me and I didn't have to modify the core code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28048236/jquery-fullcalendar-adds-weird-hr-at-the-end-of-the-calendar-when-using-mintime