# jQuery fullcalendar adds weird hr at the end of the calendar when using minTime and maxTime

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

This is what I'm talking about:
[image: What it looks like]
And this is what I expect:
[image: What I expect]

The minimal settings to replicate this are:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',           
    minTime: '10:00',
    maxTime: '16:00'         
});
```

You can play with it in [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/xelijuwoki/1/edit?js,output).

Removing either `minTime` or `maxTime` makes the calendar behave as expected.

Comment: its working as expected

Comment: @NaeemShaikh How could that be expected? And is it possible to remove that line?

Comment: its just a calender where you are setting the min and max time.. and it is working.. isnt it?

Comment: @NaeemShaikh I've updated the question to highlight what I mean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some fiddling, it appears that the default [aspect ratio](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/aspectRatio/) is `1.35`. Because your calendar doesn't meet that ratio, it is adding padding.

There are 2 options that I can see that would fix it.

(1) Modify the aspect ratio. In your example a ratio of `2.2` might work:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    allDaySlot: false,            
    minTime: '10:00',
    maxTime: '16:00',
    aspectRatio: 2.2
});
```

(2) Set [height](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/height/) to `auto`. This will make the calendar the natural height, but it will *not* allow for scrollbars:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    allDaySlot: false,            
    minTime: '10:00',
    maxTime: '16:00',
    height: 'auto'
});
```

Comment: I also looked into the aspectRatio but that's not an option for me, since the `minTime` and `maxTime` values are dynamic (selected by the user), but the `height` appears to be a life saver, I just thought it was `auto` by default. Thanks a lot.